# Kismet - How get MAC address, dbm_signal and time stamp?

Tags: kismet-wireless

I´m trying get the macadd, signal dbm and time stamp from devices near of my access point but I don´t know what the best approach to achive that.

I wrote a small client (using python) to connect Kismet using the TCP port 2501.

My script use "client protocol" from Kismet but I´m having some doubts.

First of all, I get data with "first date" and "last date" like that (datetime in timestamp):

```
mac    signal_dbm    firsttime              last time 
================================================================== 
AAAA   -81           10/04/2015 18:20:21    10/04/2015 18:27:12 
AAAA   -79           10/04/2015 18:23:38    10/04/2015 18:26:42
```

Whats is the meaning of this data and dates??

In fact I would like get data from Kismet like that.

```
mac    signal_dbm    timestamp 
==================================================================== 
AAAA   -81           10/04/2015 18:20:21 
AAAA   -81           10/04/2015 18:20:26 
AAAA   -79           10/04/2015 18:20:31 
...
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Julio Schurt

Answer (score 0):

I believe the purpose of the `firstime` and `lasttime` fields is to let you know when a client was first noticed by Kismet and when it was most recently seen.

The idea is that you can tell how long a client has been connected by working out the difference between the two, and if a client has a `lasttime` in the past you can work out how long it's been disconnected for.